# Regtest mode lose blocks?

Tags: bitcoind, regtest

I'm playing with bitcoind, I'm an started in this subject and I'm playing with the regtest=1 option of course.
The thing is that after one day all the transactions are lost, I'm trying to get the balance of some wallets and it's always 0.
Is this something related to the regtest mode? has someone had the same issue? If I restart bitcoind again everything is working as expected but is annoying since I have to create a lot of transactions again.

Comment: What do you see in `bitcoin-cli listwallets` and then using one of the names in `bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet="W1" getwalletinfo`? (Replace W1 with your wallet name)

Comment: I'm getting a balance of 0. Also I can not fetch old transactions, this is happening after running regtest mode for a week (more o less)

Comment: How many wallets do you see in the first command? Are  you using the same data directory?

Comment: Sorry the first command should be `bitcoin-cli listwalletdir` and use [`loadwallet`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/loadwallet/) if its not loaded but exists

Comment: I see the same issue using bitcoind 0.21.1

Comment: The same here for 0.25. Any solution?